# How to select random rows with distinct user (ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a trouble with selecting two random photos of different users... It would be awesome if u could help me :)

So, lets say that my own user_id=1. We don't need that also.

Table looks something like this:

```
|----------------------------|
| id | user_id | url | score |
|----------------------------|
| 1  | 1       | A   | 15    |
| 2  | 1       | B   | 5     |
| 3  | 2       | C   | 1     |
| 4  | 2       | D   | 51    |
| 5  | 2       | E   | 2     |
| 6  | 2       | F   | 9     |
| 7  | 3       | G   | 7     |
| 8  | 3       | H   | 3     |
| 9  | 3       | I   | 88    |
| 10 | 4       | J   | 15    |
| 11 | 4       | K   | 0     |
| .. | ...     | ..  | ...   |
|----------------------------|
```

So as I'm user 1, I don't have to get lines where user_id=1.

I need two random rows of two other users. And those rows cant be of same user also. In short - not me and not other 2 same users.

E.g.

```
| 5  | 2       | E   | 2     |
| 8  | 3       | H   | 3     |
or
| 8  | 3       | H   | 3     |
| 11 | 4       | K   | 0     |
or
| 10 | 4       | J   | 15    |
| 3  | 2       | C   | 1     |
```

SQL query would be OK. But if u can provide it in Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord structure it would be cool.

EDIT:

What I have tried:

```
@photos = Photo.order('RANDOM()').where.not(:user_id => current_user.id).limit(2).uniq(:user_id)

@photos = Photo.order('RANDOM()').where.not(:user_id => current_user.id).limit(2).distinct(:user_id)

@photos = Photo.distinct(:user_id).random(2)

@photos = Photo.uniq(:user_id).random(2)
```

P.S. random() came from gem "randumb". No big impact I think.

EDIT 2:

This works

```
@photos = []
@photo1 = Photo.order('RANDOM()').where.not(:user_id => current_user.id).first
@photo2 = Photo.order('RANDOM()').where.not(:user_id => current_user.id, :user_id => @photo1.user_id).first
@photos << @photo1 << @photo2
```

Comment: In your query, you could try doing SELECT DISTINCT and ordering by something random to retrieve random records: http://davidwalsh.name/mysql-random

Comment: I have edited question a little

Comment: What are the symptoms of your problem? Are you not getting back the data you need, or are you seeing some kind of error?

Comment: The problem is that I get two rows of the same user sometimes. (To imagine better the reason: this is photo contest. Same users photos can't compete. Only with other users photos. And user can't vote for its own images also) :)

Comment: i could simply select 1st candidate and then make second query. But I thought maybe there's some very smart way to do that :)

Comment: You have to include the DISTINCT in the query itself, otherwise you could return 2 records with the same user ID. Have you tried `@photos = Photo.distinct(:user_id).order('RANDOM()').limit(2)`?

Comment: Yes. I see query in console: SELECT DISTINCT "photos".* FROM "photos" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2 . Not good.

Comment: Photo.order('RANDOM()').select(:user_id).distinct.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)
Try like that, I think that you need to specify the select so it can know which field have to use, otherwise it will use the table id, that is of course, distinct for all cases.

Comment: It selects only user_id in this case. I need properties of full row :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this will get you a random picture of a given user

```
Photo.where("user_id = ?",<USER_ID>).shuffle.first
```

Now you need 2 distinct users which are not current users

```
Photo.select("distinct user_id").where("user_id <> ?",<CURRENT_USER>).shuffle.first(2)
```

And now everything in one shot

```
@photos = []
unique_user_cnt = 2
Photo.select("distinct user_id").where("user_id <> ?",<CURRENT_USER>).shuffle.first(unique_user_cnt).each do |p|
  @photos << Photo.where("user_id = ?",p.user_id).shuffle.first
end
```

Comment: It looks like this method allows to use as many different photos as u want. I'll check this out, thanks